How do I get PGAdmin to function properly
I am having trouble accessing the PGAdmin software. I get a fatal error message "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:"... what do I need to do to fix this?

We need a lot more information

Chances are, you fell victim to a bug that was fixed in the latest release pgAdmin 8.12.
The release notes

Issue #7571 - Fixed an issue where users could not use pgAdmin if they did not have access to the management database.

